# If touch a control, how can I get this control name?

Tags: c#, wpf

After I touch a control, such as Button, How can I get this button's name?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "click" instead of "touch", put something like this in your View XAML file:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" MouseDown="MyButton_MouseDown">
```

Then add following lines to the View CODE file:

```
  void MyButton_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        var control = sender as FrameworkElement;
        Console.WriteLine(control.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `click` on a control you are raising an event which called : `Control_Click`

Then you can do whatever you want in that even. As you asked about button I'm gonna show you how you can get button's name . You can have the similar code for other controls :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string control_name = button1.Name;
        MessageBox.Show(control_name);
    }
```